# Not able to update MYSQL db with python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

Issue: The script runs successfully without any errors but Mysql database won't get updated with script results

I have added line `db.autocommit(True)` to commit every time but still, it fails.

Env: python2.7, MySQL

I have also tried to manually enter `db.commit()` after each executes the statement with locks but then also it fails.

```
'''
Specifications:
A multi-Threaded Web Spider that:
Takes website and depth of spidering as input
Downloads the HTML files only
Inserts the HTML into an MYSQL database
It also parses the forms on each page and inserts into db with form details

''' 

import mechanize
import sys
import threading
import MySQLdb

lock  = threading.Lock()

def Parse_Forms(target,curr,br):
    lock.acquire()
    br.open(target)
    curr.execute("use web;");
    response = []
    for forms in br.forms():
        i= 0
        action =  forms.action
        method = forms.method
        d = dict()
        d['method'] = method
        d['name'] = action
        br.select_form(nr=i)
        for control in forms.controls:

            if control.value == '':
                d[control.name] = "NULL"
            elif type(control.value) is list:
                    d[control.name] = control.value[0]
            else:
                d[control.name] = control.value

        for j in d: 
            if str(j) == 'login' or str(j) == 'name' or str(j) == 'password' or str(j) == 'method':     #These are only the valid names that has to be inserted in MYSQL db
                query = "INSERT INTO `forms` ("+str(j)+") values (\""+str(d[j])+"\");"
                curr.execute(query)

        print "Query Executed!" 
        i=i+1
        response.append(br.submit())
        lock.release()

def getHTMLfiles(target,curr):

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    headers = [('User-Agent','Firefoxy'),]
    br.addheaders = headers
    br.open(target)
    for i in range(0,depth):
        for link in br.links():
            if ".hmtl" in link.url:
                print "Downloading File: "+link.url
                os.system("wget "+link.url+" -P Files/")
                curr.execute("INSERT INTO `pages` (name) values ("+ "\"link.url\");")
            if link.url[0] == '/' and not '.' in link.url:     #Indicates that file belongs to server not some external link and is a directory
                Parse_Forms(target+link.url,curr,br,db)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="****",password="*****",db="web") 
    #There are 2 db one called pages that saves HTML file url and one forms that saves form parameteres
    db.autocommit(True)
    curr = db.cursor()
    target = sys.argv[1]
    depth = int(sys.argv[2])
    threads = []

    for workers in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target = getHTMLfiles,args = (target,curr,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

The script works fine but it is supposed to update the MySQL database.

Note: There are no MYSQL errors(I mean literally no errors) to everything seems to run fine

Comment: ___Note : There are no MYSQL errors___ Is that strictly true? Or does it mean you are not actually looking for them. This is a question as I am not a Python guy

Comment: Yes it is strictly true. There are no MYSQL errors.